# Strange behavior of Angular UI grid scrolling with Chromium version 96

Tags: angular, angular-ui

I have upgraded chromium version (Edge Chromium/Chrome) to 96 from 87. I used Angular UI grid to display the data. When I try to scroll, it keeps comes to top and not letting me scroll down. This works fine in IE. Appreciate if you share any work around ?

Comment: Can you please provide a code sample, the steps to reproduce this issue and possibly a codepen (https://codepen.io/pen/) or similar?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.